# Pagina em branco quando se da reload no firebase

Tags: react, firebase, react-router

Bom dia/tarde/noite. Estou desenvolvendo um sistema web e para isso estou utilizando **React** como framework e para gerenciamento de rotas estou utilizando o **React Router.** O problema que estou tendo é que: em minha maquina local quando se da um reload na pagina ou se acessa através da URL ele funciona normalmente(carrega a pagina e suas funcionalidades). Porém quando dou deploy utilizando o **Firebase** e faço a mesma coisa acabo tendo uma pagina em branco.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a solucionar este problema?

**Obs.:**
**Quando dou f12 e vejo o que o servidor retornou para o meu navegador, vejo que ele tem a seguinte estrutura de pastas:**

- #### NOMEDAROTA(PASTA)

  - **nomedarota** (arquivo sem extensão, com o HTML do index.HTML)
  - **index.bundle.js** (conteúdo dele com o HTML do index.html)
  - **main.css** (conteúdo dele com o HTML do index.html)

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  output: { 
    path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "index.bundle.js" 
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
  devServer: { 
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "src"), 
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["ts-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|svg)$/,
        use: ["file-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use:["html-loader"],
      }
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
                cache: true,
                parallel: true,
                sourceMap: false,
                extractComments: 'all',
                uglifyOptions: {
                    compress: true,
                    output: null
                }
            }),
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.html"),
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
  ],
};
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

App.tsx

```
export function App(){
  return (
    <blocContext.Provider value={sessionBlocFactory()}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact 
            path='/' 
            render={() => (
              <SignInFactory/>
            )}
          />
          <Route 
            exact 
            path='/precadastro' 
            render={() => (
              <SignUpFactory/>
            )}
          />
          <Route 
            exact 
            path='/novasenha/auth/:action' 
            render={() => (
              <ResetPassword />
            )}
          />
          <ProtectedRoute
            authenticationPath='/'
            exact
            path='/admin/parceiros'
            render={() => {
              return (<PartnerPage title={"Parceiros"}/>)
            }}
          />
          <ProtectedRoute
            authenticationPath='/'
            exact
            path='/admin/produtos'
            render={() => {
              return (<ProductPage title={"Produtos"}/>)
            }}
          />
          <ProtectedRoute
            authenticationPath='/'
            exact
            path='/admin/trocas'
            render={() => {
              return (<TradesPage title={"Trocas"}/>)
            }}
          />
          <ProtectedRoute
            authenticationPath='/'
            path='/admin/parceiros/:partnerUid/cupons'
            render={(props) => {
              const aux = props.location.state as any
              const partner = new Partner(
                aux.uid, 
                aux.fantasyName, 
                aux.socialName, 
                aux.cnpj, 
                aux.address, 
                aux.phoneNumber, 
                aux.email, 
                aux.website, 
                aux.socialMedias, 
                aux.proposal, 
                aux.representative, 
                aux.sector, 
                aux.status, 
                aux.user
              );
              return  (<CouponAdminSystemPage title='Cupons' partner={partner}/>)
            }}
          />
          <ProtectedRoute
            authenticationPath='/'
            exact
            path='/admin/relatorios'
            render={() => {
              return (<TradesPage title={"Relatórios"}/>)
            }}
          />
          <ProtectedRoute
            authenticationPath='/'
            exact
            path='/parceiro/validar'
            render={() => {
              return (<ValidatePage title={"Validar Cupom"}/>)
            }}
          />
          <ProtectedRoute
            authenticationPath='/'
            exact
            path='/parceiro/cupons'
            render={() => {
              return (<CouponPage title={"Cupons"}/>)
            }}
          />
          <ProtectedRoute
            authenticationPath='/'
            exact
            path='/parceiro/contrato'
            render={() => {
              return (<ContractPage title={"Contrato"}/>)
            }}
          />
          <ProtectedRoute
            authenticationPath='/'
            exact
            path='/parceiro/relatorios'
            render={() => {
              return (<h1>Tela ainda não criada...</h1>)
            }}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path='*'
            render={() => {
              return <div>ERROR</div>
            }}
          />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </blocContext.Provider>
  )
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>Unimed Cascavel - Clube Cuidar Bem</title>
  <script defer="defer" src="/index.bundle.js"></script>
  <link href="/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

comando para gerar o build:

```
webpack --mode=production --stats-error-details
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1):

O problema foi resolvido ao colocar um **/** na tag **script** e na do **css** do index.html gerado pelo webpack.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).